# Sending message to windows service by web page

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How could I do this with no **access denied** problem?

I have a windows service:

```
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{        
    if (command == 1)
    {
      foreach (Process traceProcess in Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad.exe"))
      {
        traceProcess.Kill();
      }                     
    }        
}
```

when I do this:

```
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ProjectManager");
if (sc != null)
    sc.ExecuteCommand(1);
```

From a windows forms it works, but not from a web page, I get access denied on `sc.ExecuteCommand`.

What is the best way for a web page to talk to a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a workaround for the permission problem; sockets.

So my service opens a local port (not available to any other machine, only local)

Then in my web page I connect to this socket and send the byte I want, and in return the service executes the code I want.

If anyone asks, I can post example code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the permissions of the the application pool identity.